# Clearing style attribute after animation and DOM re-ordering

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, dom

This is for a board game where tiles are repositioned with each move but I'm getting an issue where if the screen is re-sized, the new positions of the tiles are not where I'm intending them to be.  This is caused by the style attribute that is inserted by the `animate()` function, but because the CSS uses percentages to set the initial positions of the tiles and the `animate()` function uses pixels, resizing the page results in the tiles being in the wrong place.

The simple solution (or so I thought) was to remove the style attribute after the repositioning occurs, but that's not working as expected.

To add more detail, I'm using the animate function to reposition the tiles, but I then have to re-order the DOM as well as re-apply the tile classes (e.g., if Tile 50 and Tile 60 are switched, I have to remove the "tile50" class and assign it to the `<div>` that used to be Tile 60 and vice versa).

The game is set up to have the computer automatically take a turn after the user, but with the way I have it coded now, it removes all "style" attributes except those related to the last move by the computer (i.e., the style attribute left over from the last execution of the animate function).  I want it to remove all style attributes.

Here's the code:

```
function boardUpdate(tile1, tile2) {

    var thisPos = [$('.'+tile1).position().left, $('.'+tile1).position().top];
    var thatPos = [$('.'+tile2).position().left, $('.'+tile2).position().top];

    if (turn % 2 === 0) {
        if (!($('.'+tile1).hasClass("paired-odd") && 
            $('.'+tile2).hasClass("paired-odd"))) {
                $('.'+tile1).addClass('paired-even');
                $('.'+tile1).removeClass('paired-odd');
                $('.'+tile2).addClass('paired-even');
                $('.'+tile2).removeClass('paired-odd');
        } else {
            return;
        }           
    } else {
        if (!($('.'+tile1).hasClass("paired-even") && 
            $('.'+tile2).hasClass("paired-even"))) {
                $('.'+tile1).addClass('paired-odd');
                $('.'+tile1).removeClass('paired-even');
                $('.'+tile2).addClass('paired-odd');
                $('.'+tile2).removeClass('paired-even');
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }                   

    //Section below animates tiles, updates 'tileX' class, and reorders DOM for new 'tileX' classes

    $('.'+tile1).animate({left: thatPos[0]}, {queue: false}, tileCleanup());
    $('.'+tile1).animate({top: thatPos[1]}, {queue: false}, tileCleanup());
    $('.'+tile2).animate({left: thisPos[0]}, {queue: false}, tileCleanup());
    $('.'+tile2).animate({top: thisPos[1]}, {queue: false}, tileCleanup());

    var thisIndex = $('.'+tile1).index();
    var thatIndex = $('.'+tile2).index();

    selectedTiles = [thisIndex, thatIndex];

    if (thatIndex > 0) {
        $('.'+tile1).insertAfter('.tile'+thatIndex, tileCleanup());
    } else {
        $('.'+tile1).insertBefore('.tile2', tileCleanup());
    }
    if (thisIndex > 0) {
        $('.'+tile2).insertAfter('.tile'+thisIndex, tileCleanup());
    } else {
        $('.'+tile2).insertBefore('.tile2', tileCleanup());
    }

    $('.tile:nth-of-type('+(thatIndex + 1)+')').addClass(tile2);
    $('.tile:nth-of-type('+(thatIndex + 1)+')').removeClass(tile1);
    $('.tile:nth-of-type('+(thisIndex + 1)+')').addClass(tile1);
    $('.tile:nth-of-type('+(thisIndex + 1)+')').removeClass(tile2);

}

function tileCleanup() {
    console.log("cleaning up")
    $('.tile').removeAttr("style");
}
```

As you can see, I put tileCleanup() functions as callbacks in multiple places.  I verified with the `console.log()` that the function was running each time but I still have the issue.

Also, just to clarify, every tile `<div>` has the "tile" class attached to it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not certain what Question is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working:

```
$('.'+tile1).animate({left: thatPos[0]}, {queue: false, complete: tileCleanup});
$('.'+tile1).animate({top: thatPos[1]}, {queue: false, complete: tileCleanup});
$('.'+tile2).animate({left: thisPos[0]}, {queue: false, complete: tileCleanup});
$('.'+tile2).animate({top: thisPos[1]}, {queue: false, complete: tileCleanup});
```

I first tried it with "tileCleanup()" instead of "tileCleanup", but as suggested by user guest271314, I needed to remove the "()" parentheses so that the function wouldn't execute immediately.